# Understanding Grafana metrics variables

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grok

Provided with some prometheus series:

```
query_duration{datname="audit_log", group="grok-pg", instance="docker.for.mac.localhost:9144", job="grok-pg", ts="21-05-19 12:18:10.965"}   14.859
query_duration{datname="audit_log", group="grok-pg", instance="docker.for.mac.localhost:9144", job="grok-pg", ts="21-05-19 12:19:27.603"}   10.082
```

Grafana is able to recognise variable datname if I assign a specific value:

[image]

However if I treat it as a variable then it does not work:

[image]

What am I missing? Thank you for your attention

Comment: How are you setting the value of the variable $datname?

Comment: I am possibly wrong about this, but I was assuming that "$datname" variable inside grafana's metric field -> would match the "datname=" inside query_duration{ prometheus series. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$datname is a [Grafana variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/) whose value needs to be set by Grafana before the expression is evaluated and sent to Prometheus to get the data.

Need to set the variable in  Settings > Variables.

[image]